# Add MQTT topics and data to chartjs

Tags: javascript, html, chart.js, mqtt

I have been searching around to find a solution to my problem, but all I have found so far has not been enough to make me solve my problem.

I have created a connection to a MQTT broker and I am able to subscribe to topics and read and display data. My problem is plotting the data to the chart as the topic and messages is received.

I have created an array to store incoming topics.

If I could get some feedback on what I might be doing wrong or if I am using any functions wrong I would appreciate it!
As I am loading the HTML file I get this error message:

> *Failed to create chart: can't acquire context from the given item*

Whenever I am receiving a message from broker I get connection lost and this message:

> *AMQJS0005E Internal error. Error Message: Cannot read property 'x-axis-0' of undefined, Stack trace: TypeError: Cannot read property 'x-axis-0' of undefined
>      [error messages](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y2Bxm.jpg)

```
var broker = 'm23.cloudmqtt.com'; // mqtt broker
var port = 35779;                 // websocket port
var topic = 'lubcos/#';           // topic to subscribe to, # for wildcard.

var myChart;
var topicArray = new Array();



// create new Paho MQTT client, connect with broker, port and client id
var client = new Paho.MQTT.Client(broker, port, "client_ID");

client.onMessageArrived = onMessageArrived;
client.onConnectionLost = onConnectionLost;

// ************************************************************************ //

// options for connecting to broker
var connectionOptions = {
  timeout: 3,
  useSSL: true,
  userName: "",
  password: "",
  onSuccess: onConnect,
  onFailure: doFail
};

// ************************************************************************ //

// on connection, print which broker it connectede to and which topic it is subscribing to
function onConnect() {
  console.log("Successfully connected to: " + broker);
  client.subscribe(topic, {qos: 0});
  console.log("Subscribed to: " + topic);
}

// ************************************************************************ //

// if connection failes, print error message
function doFail(message) {
  console.log("Connection failed: " + message.errorMessage);
}

// ************************************************************************ //

// when connection to the broker is lost print error message
// if connection is lost, try to reconnect
function onConnectionLost(responseObject) {
  console.log("connection lost: " + responseObject.errorMessage);
  //window.setTimeout(location.reload(),5000);
};

// ************************************************************************ //

// when message arrives it should print out topic and message to console
// if the index to the topic is < 0, it should push the topic to the array called
// mqttTopics.

function onMessageArrived(message) {
  // print out topic and data to console
  console.log("Topic: " + message.destinationName, ' | ', "Data: " + message.payloadString);

  // check if it is a new topic, if not, add to array
  if (topicArray.indexOf(message.destinationName) < 0){
    // add new topic to array
    topicArray.push(message.destinationName);
    // get the index number
    var y = topicArray.indexOf(message.destinationName);
    console.log("Topic Array: " + topicArray + " | " + "Index number: " + y);

    // create new dadta series for the chart
    var newdata = {
      id: y,
      name: message.destinationName,
      data: []
    };
    // add data to chart
    myChart.update(newdata);
  }


};



// ************************************************************************ //

// checks if the number is really a number
function isNumber(n) {
  return !isNaN(parseFloat(n)) && isFinite(n);
};

// ************************************************************************ //

// connect to client by using the information from the option variable
function init() {
  client.connect(connectionOptions);
};

// ************************************************************************ //

function plot(point, chartno) {
  console.log(point);

      var series = myChart.newData[0],

      shift = newData.data.length > 200;

      myChart.update[chartno].addPoint(point, true, shift);

};

// ************************************************************************ //

var graphOptions = {
    responsive: true,
    title: {
        display: true,
        position: "top",
        text: "LubCos H20plus II",
        fontSize: 18,
        fontColor: "#111"
    },
    legend: {
        display: true,
        position: "bottom",
        labels: {
            fontColor: "#333",
            fontSize: 16
        }
    },
  scales: {
    xAxis: [{
      type: 'realtime', // x axis will scroll from right to left
      text: 'Time',
      margin: 30
    }],
    yAxis: [{
      minPadding: 0.2,
      maxPadding: 0.2,
      title: {
        text: 'Temp °C / Humidity %',
          margin: 80
      }
    }]
  }
};

// ************************************************************************ //

    var chartData = {
      labels: ["topic"],
      datasets: [{
        label: "Topic",
        data: ["data"],
        fill: false,
        lineTension: 0,
        radius: 2
      }]
    }

// ************************************************************************ //

 $(document).ready(function() {
   var ctx = $("#line-chartcanvas");

   myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
     type: 'line',
     data: chartData,
     options: graphOptions
   });

 });
```

index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Sensor Values MQTT</title>

<link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet">

<!-- Include JavaScript classes after which order they are used in -->
<script src="js/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/chart.min.js"></script>
<!-- Eclipse Paho library for MQTT -->
<script src="js/mqttws31.js"></script>

<script src="js/browserMqtt.js"></script>
<script src="js/mqttGraph.js"></script>

</head>

<body>
<!-- Start connection to the MQTT broker by running init function -->
<body onload="init();">

<!-- Include the chart container and insert the line graph -->
<div class="chart-container">
<canvas>Chart goes here</canvas>
</div>


</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Please edit the question to include the following: 1)actual code, not a link to it 2) a proper description of what's not working. If you just want a code review then you should post to codereview not Stack Overflow (https://codereview.stackexchange.com/)

Answer (score 1):

You are defining `var chart;` in line 7.

But you are using the variable **myChart** in the function

```
$(document).ready(function () {
       var myChart = new Chart(...)
}
```

So using the function `chart.addSeries(...)` can never work.

---

EDIT: (according to hardillb´s comment)

```
var myChart;

function onMessageArrived(message){
   ...

    myChart.addSeries(newseries);
}

$(document).ready(function() {
    ...

   //leave the var
    myChart = new Chart(ctx, {...});
});
```

---

EDIT2:

The first error is probably related to the `var ctx = $("#line-chartcanvas");` part.
In your HTML you need to give the canvas an ID with the same name as in your JavaScript code:

```
<!-- Include the chart container and insert the line graph -->
<div class="chart-container">
    <canvas id=line-chartcanvas>Chart goes here</canvas>
</div>
```

Your second error seems to be coming from this part:

```
function onMessageArrived(message) {
  // print out topic and data to console
  console.log("Topic: " + message.destinationName, ' | ', "Data: " + message.payloadString);

  // check if it is a new topic, if not, add to array
  if (topicArray.indexOf(message.destinationName) < 0){
    // add new topic to array
    topicArray.push(message.destinationName);
    // get the index number
    var y = topicArray.indexOf(message.destinationName);
    console.log("Topic Array: " + topicArray + " | " + "Index number: " + y);

    // create new dadta series for the chart
    var newdata = {
      id: y,
      name: message.destinationName,
      data: []
    };
    // add data to chart
    myChart.update(newdata);
  }
};
```

You are trying to add data to the chart with `myChart.update(newdata);` but it doesn´t seem like what the Charts.js library is expecting as parameters. Also you are always passing in an empty data array.

You should check the Charts.js documentation on how to properly use the update function:
https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/developers/updates.html

Comment: I renamed the variable to myChart in line 7 along with the chart variable in the rest of my code. Still getting the same error.

Comment: Can you please update the code in the question so we can have a look?

Comment: You need to remove the `var` from before `myChart = new Chart(...)`. This is creating a new local variable not reusing the one in the wider scope.

Comment: I have fixed the variable mistake. Do you have a chance to take a look at it now? I am getting different errors this time.

Comment: I edited my answer to address the other errors. You should check the Chart.js documentation to see how it is properly used. You´ll also find a lot of questions regarding the Chart.js library on StackOverflow